Python image to text conversion
(https://i.sstatic.net/Bw299Dzu.png)
The above image I have attempted to getting the text from it using the below code:
    from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
    import pytesseract
    def solve_captcha(image_path):
        try:
            img = Image.open(image_path)
            img = img.convert("L")
            img = img.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config="--psm 6")
            return text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            return ""

    captcha_text = solve_captcha("aeml_captcha_page.png")
    print("CAPTCHA Text:", captcha_text)
    exit()

This code doesn't work properly and the captcha text value I am getting is "i #56 to ®" instead of ifSL96
